# Memory error with recursive function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, function, recursion

I have the below recursive function in MATLAB but keep getting an "out of memory" error.

Should I be using use an iterative method instead? If so, how might I go about doing that?

```
function [Result] = Test(n)
    % Test(0) = 0
    if n > 0
        Result = 1+(31/45)*Test(n-1)+(1/5)*Test(n+2)+(1/9)*Test(n+5);
    else
        Result = 0;
    end
end
```

This does not need to go to infinity but merely a sufficiently large `n`.

Comment: An iterative approach would possibly be a lot better.

Comment: I've suspected this but am unsure how to convert the above into an iterative function.

Comment: Actually by looking at the the formula for your `Result` I sense something weird.. to calculate `Test(n)` you need `Test(n+2)` and for that you would need `Test(n+4)` and `Test(n+6)`..if `n` is a positive number this does not stop, and if `n` is a negative number the same issue arises due to `Test(n-1)` in the formula. To sum it up, recursive formulations are supposed to represent the solution with smaller subproblems, the exact opposite is happening here. Maybe the original problem has some bounds on `n` ?

Comment: @LMY Did you find the solution helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should rewrite the recursive function like the following:

```
T(n) = 1 + (31/45)*T(n-1) + (1/5)*T(n+2) + 1/9*T(n+5)
suppose: i = n + 5 => T(i-5) = 1 + (31/45)*T(i-4) + (1/5)*T(i-3) + 1/9*T(i)
=> T(i) = 9*T(i-5) - (31/5)*T(i-4) - (9/5)*T(i-3) - 9
```

So `T(1) = T(2) = T(3) = -9, T(4) = 36/5`. Therefore you can iterate like the following:

```
function Result = Test(n)
T = zeros(1,n);
T(1) = -9; 
T(2) = -9; 
T(3) = -9;
T(4) =  36/5;
T(5) = 63;
for i = 6 : n
    T(i) = 9*T(i-5) - (31/5)*T(i-4) - (9/5)*T(i-3) - 9; 
end
Result = T(n);
```

Comment: The rewrite thing is smart, I totally missed it !